How do I sort the output of tbl_custom_summary by row sum?
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

data <- tibble(
  id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  report = c("A,B","A","B,C","A,B,C","A,B,C")) %>% 
  mutate(b_present = ifelse(str_detect(report, "B"), "Yes", "No"))

n_patients <- nrow(data) # number of patients, not reports

custom_percent <- function(data, ...) {
n <- nrow(data)
pct <- round(100*n/n_patients, 1)
dplyr::tibble(pt_n = n, pt_pct = pct)
}

data %>% 
  separate_rows(report, sep = ",") %>% 
  group_by(b_present, report) %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  tbl_custom_summary(by="b_present",
  stat_fns = all_categorical() ~ custom_percent, 
  statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{pt_n} ({pt_pct})") 


How do I sort the factors by frequency? In this case B,A,C. I have a large number of rows and would like to use gtsummary to do this, although I am open to other ways.

You can re-order the levels by making your variable a factor. Example below!
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

data <- 
  tibble(
    id = c(1,2,3,4,5),
    report = c("A,B","A","B,C","A,B,C","A,B,C")
  ) |> 
  mutate(b_present = ifelse(str_detect(report, "B"), "Yes", "No"))

n_patients <- nrow(data)

custom_percent <- function(data, ...) {
  n <- nrow(data)
  pct <- round(100*n/n_patients, 1)
  dplyr::tibble(pt_n = n, pt_pct = pct)
}

data |>  
  separate_rows(report, sep = ",") |> 
  mutate(report = factor(report, levels = c("B", "A", "C"))) |> # ADD THIS LINE!
  tbl_custom_summary(
    by = "b_present",
    include = -id,
    stat_fns = all_categorical() ~ custom_percent, 
    statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{pt_n} ({pt_pct})"
  ) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO




Characteristic
No, N = 1
Yes, N = 10




report




B
0.00 (0.00)
4.0 (80)


A
1.0 (20)
3.0 (60)


C
0.00 (0.00)
3.0 (60)



Created on 2024-06-24 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks! What if I don't know the ordering of the factors? I want gtsummary to order them by the frequency it calculates for each level of the factor.
